# JSON jQuery data variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a little problem. I want ot get information for current user from json url, but my Username is in variable. When I try to get and show information for current user name by (`$('#result').append(data.users.Username);`) nothing happans. But if you do `$('#result').append(data.users.Admin);` everything is work. My question is how to get infromation for current user when username is in variable? I will be very thankful if someone help. Thanks.

```
$('#start').on('click', function() {
    var Username = $('#Username').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'jsonurl,
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $('#result').html('');
        $('#result').append(data.users.Username);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation `[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), like so

```
data.users[Username]
```